# Notepad++, installed through snap install, has a menu bar with very small letters

Tags: debian, gnome, snap

I have installed `notepad++` using a `snap` command under my `GNOME` session on `Debian 10`.

```bsh
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

It works fine, except that its menu bar has a font that is too small.

[image: Notepad++ running. It's menu bar font is smaller than the one I have for others applications]

Other applications ran on my session have a menu bar font that is two points higher. It is also normal if I install `Notepad++` on a `Windows` system.

Do I have a way to correct this displaying ? Does either `snap`, `notepad++` or the underlying `wine` (? I don't know, if it's the case, here ?), lacking something in their installations ?

Answer (score 3):

As a default through installing Notepad++ through WINE or SNAP the fonts are extremely tiny. As explained in this [link](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-notepad-plus-plus.html), you need to copy the user.reg file which contains all the font details using `cp ~/.wine/user.reg /home/(user)/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/` and change the file details.

I have read there is also another way by typing in `winecfg` in the terminal and changing the screen resolution DPI through the graphics if that helps, or even changing the font size through `Settings > Style Config > Global Styles > Default Style`.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, type in the command `notepad-plus-plus.wine winecfg`. A pop-up window labeled "Wine configuration" will appear. Then go to the "Graphics" tab and increase you dpi resolution in the slide bar as desired.

Typing `winecfg` in the terminal and changing the screen resolution DPI there did not fix it for me. These seem to be different settings, as the dpi resolution can be different in each.

[image: Wine configuration window]